# BufferedImage class

Tags: java, android, bufferedimage

I am attempting to modify an existing open source code that will compare two images so that I can create a VERY rudimentary retina scanner as an Android app. However, the code uses the `BufferedImage` subclass. My problem is that `BufferedImage` keeps returning as an unresolved symbol, and I am worried this may be because I actually have to create the subclass, even though I thought it was part of the Java library.

Am I right? Or is there something I'm missing? And if I am right, could someone provide me with a direction on actually making the subclass? If it helps, my platform is Android Studio 0.8.14.

Comment: yeah, you are missing obvious thing, that awt is not a part of android's framework/API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BufferedImage belongs to the awt package and isn't available on Android :/

[docs.oracle.com -> BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

However you can use the **Bitmap class**.It should get you to where you wanna go.

[Android Developer - Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

[Android Developer - Guide for working with Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, knew something was wrong. Just couldn't figure out what.